# Can I test desktop apps with MonkeyTalk?

Tags: android, android-emulator, desktop-application, automated-tests, monkeytalk

I am using MonkeyTalk for automated testing of Android apps. Is it possible to test Destop apps also by using MonkeyTalk. If yes, please instruct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It supports native mobile iOS and Android apps and web apps. There is no support for desktop apps. See more here: http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk/features-benefits

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no support for destop apps testing with MonkeyTalk. Since MonkeyTalk supports agents for iOS and Android, currently it supports Android and iOS testing. Please see the FAQ (General section):

[MonkeyTalk FAQ](http://gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-faq)